# For FBX export: armature, then subdivision or the other way?

Tags: rigging, armature, unity, subdivision-surface, unreal-engine

So I've been making some rigs lately, and I found that using the armature modifier first, and after that the sub-surf gives some good results, especially on facial rigs. The question is that in some point I want to start exporting those models and animations to a game engine, and I don't know if exporting fbx's with that modifier order can cause problems. I can't test it right now on unity or unreal.

First sub-surf, then armature
[image: Test1]

First armature, then sub-surf
[image: Test2]

What would be the best practice?

Comment: but you won't be able to export your file with the Subdivision Surface modifier, no?

Comment: to my undestanding, it applies the subdivision if you click on a checkbox when exporting. but I don't know how it will behave when you change the modifiers order outside of blender.

Comment: within Blender it gives a better result to put the Subsurf below the Armature, but I don't know what happens when you export

Comment: FBX can export subsurf modifiers (there's an option for it). For a game, normally you'd want subsurf, then arma though. The subsurf would be applied in the asset pipeline, and the game engine would only have to do the arma at runtime.